# PHP require_once two files with the same name

Tags: php

This is a weird situation... I'm trying to create an extension for a PHP program "A" which integrates with another program "B".

Here's the problem, both "A" and "B" have files named "config.php", containing their configuration. So what happens is that script A has:

```
requice_once("config.php");
...
require_once("../B/something.php");
```

Then "something.php" also has

```
require_once("config.php");
```

Which is a different file because it's in a different directory - But PHP doesn't notice that and the second file is not included.

I managed to find a really ugly solution of renaming the second "config.php" as well as all references to it but this will obviously make maintenance a pain... is there a better way?

EDIT -

OK, Maybe I oversimplified a little bit. "A" is actually "phpBB", for which I'm writing an extension (and I don't want to start modifying the main program because it'll make maintenance unbearable), so I can't make any changes to the code that includes the first instance of config. I implement an API by extending a given base class, then phpBB calls my class' __construct method with one of the arguments being $phpbb_root_path, which is the directory where phpBB is installed. Then from the extension I do this:

```
require_once($phpbb_root_path . "../B/something.php");
```

"B" is an in-house developed package (not yet open-source so I can't give exact file names), that why it was easier for me to rename "config.php" to "configuration.php" for an ugly fix. Everything there is in a single directory. The exact tree is

```
htdocs
  | - phpbb
  |     |
  |     | - config.php
  |     | - ext/{long path}/myextension.php
  |
  | --- B
  |     | - config.php
  |     | - something.php
```

Thanks, sorry for the big explantion.

Comment: `chdir('../B');` then require, then `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));` after

Comment: `require_once("config.php");` does not tell PHP where is located the file to include (`config.php` in this case). It has some rules to search it and, most probably, on the second call the file `config.php` resolves to the same file as on the first call. Consequently PHP does not include it again. Use `dirname()` and `__DIR__` to compute the absolute path of `config.php` in both places and it will work. Read [this answer](/a/29437160/4265352), [this answer](/a/35033901/4265352), [this answer](/a/42691425/4265352) and [this answer](/a/36112325/4265352) (only the first part matches).

Comment: If the files are in a different directory then you should put the full directory path into the require call.

Comment: Also you should not be wrapping `require` (or `include`) values in brackets. Quotes are enough

Comment: If you need further details on how to fix your issue then please edit your question and show the directory tree of the relevant files (including the file calling the `require`) and the document root of the domain

Comment: looks like you have a syntax error elsewhere in your file as the 'require_once' statements are showing as two different colours in your editor.  Also remove the () around the file name and shows as requice_once "config.php";  It doesn't matter how many times you use require_once it will only ever get included once.

Comment: Edited according to your resposes.

Comment: @Dan thanks. is your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` directory the `htdocs`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `htdocs` directory is your PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` location, then you can simply include the files using better specificity.

You need to specify not only which file you want, but *where exactly the file is located*.

so; from your edit showing your file tree:

```
requice_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/phpbb/config.php";
...
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/B/something.php";
```

Then "something.php" also has

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/B/config.php";
```

## NOTES

- You should not wrap `include` or `require` values in brackets.
- You should not use *relative pathing* (`..`, etc.), always give an **absolute** filepath.
- Generally, try and avoid using `_once` functions they are heavy lifters, and expensive with memory and you probably don't need them (especially if you're absolutely pathing)
- Even if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not the *exact* solution for your situation, you can take the *concept* given here and apply it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Martin, The only issue with your answer is that the code that includes "/phpbb/config.php" is part of the main phpBB package and runs a lot earlier before my extension is called - in other words that part of the code is read-only from my perspective. I can only modify the extension (or if really needed, the "B" package). How would you approach it in that situation?

Comment: Then "something.php" also has `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/B/config.php";`